# Custom Workflow _ Alfresco Community

Tags: alfresco

I need to create a new Custom Workflow in Alfresco.
I followed this tutorial : [Creating Custom Workflow in Alfresco](http://alfrescosolutionsv.blogspot.com/2013/07/creating-custom-workflow-in-alfresco.html#more)

But I couldn't find the two files in my Alfresco:

- share-workflow-form-config.xml that must be in 
  Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco
- bootstrap-context.xml that must be in 
  Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\alfresco\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco

I'm using Alfresco Community Edition 5.1 under Windows 8

Can I add those two files to My Alfresco ? If so, where can I find them ?

Comment: hey Hajer! Check this turorial, it's more up to date than the one you're following : http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/workflow/tutorial/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

You should not be modifying the two files that you have listed.  It goes against best practices and they are no longer exposed in exploded webapps (you can find them inside of their respective jars).

For tutorial purposes you should use the shared classpath folder.  If you're using the all-in-one installer, then that location is: `$CATALINA_HOME/shared/classes/alfresco/`

As an example: `C:/alfresco-one/tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco`

In a simplistic approach, you should add your Share form config for workflows to the `share-config-custom.xml` file located in the shared web-extension location (`$CATALINA_HOME/shared/classes/alfresco/web-extension/share-config-custom.xml`)

Add your bootstrap config to a custom context file in the shared extension location:
(`$CATALINA_HOME/shared/classes/alfresco/extension/foobar-bootstrap-context.xml`)